# one way file sync with unison or better alternative

Tags: synchronization, tcpdump, unison

I have been collecting a logs for user actions on the network using a program similar to tcpdumps; with every millisecond the file being written to. I am currently using [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to synchronize the logs to a centralized server. Occasionally during the synchronization process it fails with this error:

```
<file> has been modified during synchronization.  Transfer aborted.
```

Is there any other alternative configuration or sync mechanism that I could use/benefit from?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [logstash](http://logstash.net/)? I use this tool to manage and aggregate some of my infrastructures logs. It uses an agent-server setup.

> logstash is a tool for managing events and logs. You can use it to
>   collect logs, parse them, and store them for later use (like, for
>   searching). Speaking of searching, logstash comes with a web interface
>   for searching and drilling into all of your logs.
>
> It is fully free and fully open source. The license is Apache 2.0,
>   meaning you are pretty much free to use it however you want in
>   whatever way.
>
> logstash is now a part of the Elasticsearch family! This allows us to
>   build better software much faster as well as offering production
>   support

Comment: I think you did not get my question well. My only purpose here is to synchronize the files. If you read the above question well, my current synchronization breaks, because log files keep writing more often.

Comment: @Muneer, Sorry, I guess I didn't. I don't know how to fix that issue with unison.

Comment: I replaced my complete sync structure with RSYNC wrapping with a custom script written in python. It works well for the scenario and looks more reliable.

Comment: @Muneer, rsync definitely seems like the way to go. Better at strictly one-way sync that Unison. You should post your setup in more detail as an answer.

Comment: @mapierce271 yes, I lost with Unison. It had some strange behavior that was difficult to sort out. Finally I wrote my own python script wrapping the `rsync` which could perform the task perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `rsync` is the right answer for this job.

However, if there are other reasons to use Unison anyhow, there is a Unison option to force all changes to propagate in one direction:

```
-force xxx         force changes from this replica to the other
```

There is even an option to force changes only for certain directories. See the excellent [Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) for a full explanation.